# Необходимо сделать ровную пирамиду(количество строк зависит от введенного значения (в данном случае 1-9)), подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде

Tags: javascript

```js
let lines = Number(prompt('Введите количество строк от 1 до 9'));
let str = '     ';
let g = 1;
if (lines < 1 || lines > 9) {
  console.log('Введите верное число');
} else {
  while (g <= lines) {
    g++;
    str += ' # ';
    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так в str количество пробелов должно уиеньшаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Небольшая модификация.

1. Убрать лишний ведущий пробел из `str += '# ';`
2. Добавить `' '.repeat(lines - g + 1)` в console.log().

```js
let lines = Number(prompt('Введите количество строк от 1 до 9'));
let str = '    ';
let g = 1;
if (lines < 1 || lines > 9) {
    console.log('Введите верное число');
} else {
    while (g <= lines) {
        g++;
        str += '# ';
        console.log(' '.repeat(lines - g + 1) + str);
    }
}
```